# Ubuntu 18 - Problem with scaner (EPSON v33)

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, epson

I've updated my Ubuntu16.04 to Ubuntu18.04.1 LTS, and now there is еру problem with scanner EPSON Perfection v33. I try to install it as I did it for ubuntu 16.04 (http://www.mogilowski.net/lang/en-us/2014/05/14/install-epson-perfection-v33-scanner-on-ubuntu-14-04/), but Image Scan doesn't see the scaner (Could not send command to scanner. Check the scanner's status).

The "sudo sane-find-scanner" found the scanner:

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x0bda [Generic], product=0x0129 [USB2.0-CRW]) at libusb:001:004
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x0142 [EPSON Perfection V33/V330]) at libusb:001:011
```

But "scanimage -L" can't see it:

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

Have anyone a similar problem with usb-scanner in Ubuntu18 or any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try;

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/sane /usr/lib
```